# sshd on yocto linux consistenaly disconnects me

Tags: sshd, yocto, arm64, lte

We have our own yocto image on IMX8 device (NXP).
The device internet is served by simcon EU 4G modem and IOT sim (Monogoto).
The connection id created with libqmi and created wwan0 successfully.

- the sshd recipe was left untouched (expcet for preventing root logins)
- the ssh access to the device is on demand, when requested ngrok forwards TCP port 22 and on ngrok site i can see my URI to connect to.

When trying to connect i'm successfull. However when i try to use commands with large output like dmesg or copy paste large test files to vi the terminal hangs and connection shuts down.
If i connect using ngrok to a regular PC the connections remains open just fine.
I thought it might be the modem. So i connected to my ubuntu using a USB similar modem (EC25e - same SIM provder though) the ssh connection was ok. Tried to compare and change the `sshd_config` settings but all the settings that were different between my laptop version and the `Compulab` (NXP)  and were changed did not seem to help.

Any idea as for why the disconnection ?
Any lead ?
Thanks.

Comment: What do the logs say during disconnect?

Comment: not much, jut messafes regarding closing down the open session account of user 1000. i didn't see much on journalctl -f so i run sshd manually with `ssh -D -p3000 -d` and after the login not much came up. i did see all the addresses were ipv6, so i used -4, but it still didn't help. currently it looks like cellular connection issue.

Comment: when connecting the compulab to ethernet and running `ifconfig wwan0 down` the ssh does not disconnect, which brings me to the conclustion that it's not ssh related but cellular connection related. only question remains is it an issue in QMI ? Simcon modem ? or the cellular provider ? i'll check with a different provider and see the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a provider APN issue, other APN's from the same provider did not have the same issue. For some reason the issue did occur with that provider only on simcon modems and not quectel modems, probably timeout definitions in the firmware. nothing much can be done on the client side.